# Смена оформления CSS

Tags: asp.net, c#, visual-studio, css

У меня есть два файла CSS со стилями для сайта. Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку менять стиль сайта. Именно всего сайта, а не конкретной странички. **Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать в asp.net?**

При этом сами сss подключаю через темы, т.е. у меня созданы две темы, в каждой папке которых лежит по СSS файлу. Для всего сайта указывают тему через Web.config -  `<pages theme="tm2"/>`. Соответственно, мне, по сути, по нажатию кнопки нужно изменить тему у в  Web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо переопределить мастер страницу и, исходя из этого, использовать те или другие стили.
Пример == [link text](http://xn----7sbab9byagn3e.xn--p1ai/).
Нажмите ссылку - Версия для слабовидящих.

Вот начало кода для этого:

```
namespace Aisha
{
    using System.Web.UI;

    public class BaseMasterPage : MasterPage
    {
        public string GetContrastUrl()
        {
            bool isContrast = !SiteType.IsContrast();
            string returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl;
            string url = string.Format("/Contrast.aspx?contrast={0}&returnUrl={1}", isContrast, returnUrl);

            return url;
        }

        public string GetMobileUrl()
        {
            bool isMobile = !SiteType.IsMobile();
            string returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl;
            string url = string.Format("/Mobile.aspx?mobile={0}&returnUrl={1}", isMobile, returnUrl);

            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

Да, я конечно не спорю, через JS так же имеется возможность достичь данного результата, но, при моем подходе, я не только меняю стили для сайта, но и всю разметку пишу на новой мастер странице.

Для меня так удобнее:

1. Обычная версия сайта - одна мастер страница
2. Мобильная версия - другая мастер страница (но можно и используя теги media) - для наглядности - [Media Query Demos](http://xn----7sbab9byagn3e.xn--p1ai/editor/Media1.htm)
3. Версия сайта для слабовидящих - третья мастер страница

Answer (score 0):

Это не в ASP.NET нужно делать, а в JS. Тегу `<link>` добавляете ID и при клике на кнопки меняете атрибут `href` у тега `<link>`

Comment: Я CSS подключаю через темы, т.е. создаю тему, в папку к ней кидаю СSS, и этот СSS автоматически подхватывается всеми с страницами, которым подключена эта тема. Для всего сайта тему подключаю через Web.config, `"<pages theme="tm2"/>"`.  
Нельзя ли после этого как-то динамически поменять эту тему?

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt Вот в тонкостях asp.net не разбираюсь. Вот как со стороны front-end'а делать, я написал, а остального, к сожалению, не знаю :)